# Replaceing a specific number from an int array

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have an array

```
int[] array={1,2,3,1,6,3,1};
```

and I want to replace all the 1 with 4. Are there any ways to do that besides changing it to a string array and use replace, then change it back?

Comment: Yes. More than one in fact, a loop should do it in O(n).

Comment: Loop through the array and check all the values inside. Change the value to 4 if the value is 1

Comment: You should not convert it into string. What if there is 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the array and swap out any 1's with 4's.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i]==1) { 
        array[i]=4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and check each element for the value you are looking for.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 1)
        array[i] = 4;
}
```